# How to covert a file to .gz extension

Tags: python, neural-network, gzip, mnist, file-conversion

I am working with MNIST data in ML(for digit recognistion) and I want to convert my 'mnist.pkl' to 'mnist.pkl.gz' because the turtorial I am watching uses that extension.[image: This is the file he uses]

**also if possible please tell me what are those ..... that he has before the file name('.../data/mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb') if you are familiar with it**     Thank You

Comment: You don't really "convert to .gz", `gz` is the gzip format. You run gzip on one or more files, and it gives you a gzip archive back. Just like zip or 7z give you a .zip file or a .7z file. Note that, because python has gzip [built in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html), you can either use gzip manually, or you can actually make python _create_ you a gzip file. Plenty of options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extension `.gz` indicates that the file was compressed using [gzip](http://mnist.pkl) which you can do by invoking

```
gzip mnist.pkl
```

on the command line. The command will remove the original file and replace it with a compressed version named `mnist.pkl.gz`.

That said, you don't have to compress/decompress the file in your particular case. Just use

```
f = open('../data.mnist.pkl', 'rb')
```

instead of

```
f = gzip.open('../data.mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
```